# Connect/disconnect from ActiveMQ topic on camel websocket connection/disconnection

Tags: websocket, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I've got the following camel route which listens for messages on an ActiveMQ topic and immediately sends them to all connected web socket clients. This is working fine, but the connection to the topic is made as soon as the route builder is initialised.

```
from("activemq:topic:mytopic").routeId("routeid").to("websocket://test?sendToAll=true");
```

What I need is to only connect to the topic when one or more clients are connected to the web socket. Once there are no more connections I want to stop listening on the topic. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me there is no proper way to do this. The only way this can be achieved is override Jetty WebSocket code. Once you override Jetty Websocket code you get the flexibility to write your own custom code in open and close websocket.

- Maintain a List for all websocket clients in open websocket. Check for close websocket and remove it from the list to know how many are connected or disconnected. Or keep a counter on open and close websocket.
- Once all websocket clients get closed suspend the route so that your messages stay in the topic or queue.
- If any client gets connected to websocket, resume the route so that the messages reach the particular client connected.

Comment: Yeah, this is correct. We could consider having a from(websocket:test?events=onConnect,onDisconnect) so you can filter on the events, and then use that as a route where you can then call controlbus to suspend/resume that other route with the AMQ topics.

Comment: @ClausIbsen The addition of those event would be definitely be helpful. It would make sense to add this to the Atmosphere-websocket component too. In the short term I was thinking that I could make use of the JMX capabilities to poll for the number of connections and suspend the route accordingly. Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah you are welcome to log a JIRA: http://camel.apache.org/support.html. If you can find the details in JMX then yeah you can use that to control the AMQ route. As you would need to schedule poll the JMX stats there is a time window where you are a bit behind.